# EC2 and git (bitbucket) and multiple users: permissions

Tags: git, permissions, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I have an Amazon EC2 instance to which I share the access (by the same ssh-key) with colleague. He has this ssh key added to his Bitbucket account. I have given him full access to my Bitbucket repository.

When he does `git pull` everything works smoothly. When I do, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)`.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: what do you mean "by the same ssh-key"? If you are using the same public key then both your clients need the same private key. Why would you do that? Have each user configure his own bitbucket account with his own public key, and grant both users access to the repo.

Comment: Hmm. 1 amazon public/private key, shared among us. When he logs in with this key to amazon box and does "git pull", it works. When I log in to that box with that same key, I get permission denied.
To me, it looks like both of us are on the same amazon account. When anybody logged in into that account does a "git pull", he should be connected to the same repo as the same bitbucket user, right?

Comment: From the errors, it looks like you are wrong... try what SébastienDawans suggests.